# VS Code: Local code w/ remote ssh-interpreter (similar to Intellij Idea Ultimate)

Tags: vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I would like to create the following setup using VS Code:

- keep code changes local (only push/deploy code for execution to ssh-connected host)
- execute code with remote python interpreter (on ssh-host)

I do NOT want to have the code editor running on the remote ssh file system, since the remote ssh-host might be deleted any time, and I would loose the code changes.

In VS Code I only managed so far to have code+execution local, or code+execution remote.

Is there a way to make this work? (it works in Intellij Idea with "SSH-Interpreter")

reading all tutorials about Remote-SSH plugin for VS Code did not gave an answer